# SQL Server cursor left join

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I'm working on a view with many select statements and calculations in the background.

One cursor query is causing a problem and I don't where to start to fix this problem.

The SQL statement below is working fine. I added `WAn_AnzTage` which is stored in `TWorkflowAntraege` and `@_wananztage` for fetching the next value. These two additions are now commented out from the script. Once I add those to the script, I get no return values anymore.

However, when I run the script as SQL query itself outside of the cursor with fixed values everything is working fine.

```
declare cur cursor for
    select 
        WPo_DatumVon, WPo_DatumBis, WPo_AbwArt, WPo_AbwTag --, WAn_AnzTage
    from 
        TWorkflowAntraege
    inner join 
        TWorkflowPool on WAn_AntragsNr = WPo_AntragsNr
    inner join 
        TAbwArt on Abw_AbwArt = WPo_AbwArt
    where 
        wan_persnr = @3 
        and (Wan_WorkflowStatus = 0 or WAn_WorkflowStatus = 4) 
        and Wan_Antragsart = 2 
        and WPo_AbwArt like @_likeabw
        and ((WPo_DatumVon >= @_date and WPo_DatumBis <= @5)
             OR (WPo_DatumVon < @_date and WPo_DatumBis >= @_date)
             OR (WPo_DatumVon < @5 and WPo_DatumBis >= @5))
        and WPo_AbwArt like @_likeabw

open cur 

fetch next from cur
      into @_datumvon, @_datumbis, @_abwart, @_abwtag --, @_wananztage

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    -- something something
    -- not touching WAn_AnzTage yet.
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Insert the records into a temp table first and then use the records from temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_TWorkflowAntraege (
    WPo_DatumVon NVARCHAR(10)
    ,WPo_DatumBis NVARCHAR(10)
    ,WPo_AbwArt NVARCHAR(10)
    ,WPo_AbwTag NVARCHAR(10)
    )

insert into #temp_TWorkflowAntraege
SELECT WPo_DatumVon
    ,WPo_DatumBis
    ,WPo_AbwArt
    ,WPo_AbwTag --, WAn_AnzTage
FROM TWorkflowAntraege
INNER JOIN TWorkflowPool ON WAn_AntragsNr = WPo_AntragsNr
INNER JOIN TAbwArt ON Abw_AbwArt = WPo_AbwArt
WHERE wan_persnr = @3 
    AND (Wan_WorkflowStatus = 0 OR WAn_WorkflowStatus = 4) 
    AND Wan_Antragsart = 2 
    AND WPo_AbwArt LIKE @_likeabw 
    AND ((WPo_DatumVon >= @_date 
    AND WPo_DatumBis <= @5) OR (WPo_DatumVon < @_date AND WPo_DatumBis >= @_date) OR (WPo_DatumVon < @5 AND WPo_DatumBis >= @5)) 
    AND WPo_AbwArt LIKE @_likeabw


DECLARE cur CURSOR
FOR
SELECT WPo_DatumVon
    ,WPo_DatumBis
    ,WPo_AbwArt
    ,WPo_AbwTag
FROM #temp_TWorkflowAntraege

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT
FROM cur
INTO @_datumvon
    ,@_datumbis
    ,@_abwart
    ,@_abwtag --, @_wananztage

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- something something
    -- not toching WAn_AnzTage yet.
END

CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Declare statement to this:

```
Declare cur Cursor Local Fast_Forward For
```

This should prevent any sort of locking or delay in generating the cursor.